# Application crashing while closing

Tags: c#

I have a c# exe which uses some c++ dlls . I use DllImport in my c# exe to use my c++ dlls.   Now my problem is when I close my application my application crashes. I am not sure why Its crashing. My c++ dll is multithreaded and my c# exe has Background worker

Comment: How does it crash?  Please post details.

Comment: A little more information would be nice. What DLLs? What procedures? What P/Invoke signatures? How/when are they used? What kind of crash? Have you pulled a stack trace out of WinDbg?

Comment: May not be relevant (hence comment rather than answer): we had similar problem under UNIX because we were loading _and unloading_ dynamic libraries, some of which registered atexit() functions (the mongrels). Then when we exited our process, those functions were called or, more precisely, whatever was there at that point was called and boom, crash, opera. Being far more UNIX-y than Windows-y, I have no idea if that would help. Still I thought I'd mention it just in case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it crash on debug or release mode ?

Have you considered putting some breakpoints ?

What does the stack trace say ?